# Why does System V traditionally symlink /bin to /usr/bin?

Tags: directory-structure, history, fhs

This [systemd wiki page about the /usr merge](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), under Myth #6, states that `/bin` has traditionally been a symlink to `/usr/bin` on System V UNIX.

What is the motivation for this? For backwards compatibility it makes sense, but I don't understand why it was like this in the early days. (Or, am I misunderstanding? Did early UNIX versions distinguish between `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, and System V changed that by merging them?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answers are, yes, it was done for compatibility (lots of programs referenced `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ed`), and in the early days `/bin` and `/usr/bin` contained totally disjoint sets of files. `/bin` was on the root filesystem, a small disk that the computer's boot firmware had to be able to access, and held the more critical and often-used files. `/usr/bin` was on `/usr`, typically an entirely separate, larger disk. `/usr`, at first, also contained users' home directories. As `/usr` grew, we would periodically replace its drive with something larger. The system could run with no `/usr` mounted, even if wasn't all that useful.

`/usr`'s disk (or disk partition) was mounted after the Unix kernel had been booted and the system was partway through the user-mode boot process (`/etc/rc`), so programs like `sh` and `mount` and `fsck` had to be in the root filesystem, generally in `/bin` and `/etc`. Sun had even rearranged `/` and `/usr` so that a shared copy of `/usr` could be mounted read-only across a network. `/usr/tmp` became a symlink to `/var/tmp`. `/var` was either on the root filesystem or, preferably, on another partition.

I believe it was Sun that decided, at one point, that it wasn't worth heroically trying to have a system be able to come up if its `/usr` was trashed. Most users either had `/` and `/usr` on the same physical disk - so if it died, both filesystems were toast - or had `/usr` mounted read-only from a server. So some critical programs used for system boot and maintenance were compiled statically and put in `/sbin`, but most of the programs in `/bin` were moved to `/usr/bin` and `/bin` became a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

System V prior to R4 didn't even have symlinks. Sun and AT&T worked to combine SunOS and SVR3, and that became SVR4 (and Solaris 2). It had `/bin` as a symlink to `/usr/bin`.

So when that web site says "On SysV Unix `/bin` traditionally has been a symlink to `/usr/bin`", they really should have said "On System V Release 4 and followons, ...".